# Make a machine a NAT router

Tags: networking, virtualbox, nat

I would like to create the following network:

Internet ---- Host machine ---- VM1 ---(local network)-- VM2

with VM1 acting as a NAT router.
VM1 and VM2 run Ubuntu via VirtualBox.

To achieve this, I created a local network 192.168.46.x for VM1 (192.168.46.101) & VM2 (192.168.46.102).
I also set the value in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward to 1 (for VM1).
In addition to that, I attached VM1 to NAT.

With this configuration, I can ping VM1 from VM2 and vice versa, and I can also ping google.com from VM1.

I thought that for being able to ping google.com from VM2, I would have just to add the following entry to VM2's routing table:

```
Dest      Gateway         Netmask        Iface
0.0.0.0   192.168.46.101  255.255.255.0  enp0s3
```

(where enp0s3 is the only network interface of VM2).

But still, VM2 gets "unknown host google.com" when pinging.

Could you help me figure out why?

[ifconfig for VM1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfKEn.png),
[ifconfig for VM2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDN9t.png),
[route -n for VM1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4g0Q.png),
[route -n for VM2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3xL4.png)

Comment: can you ping `8.8.8.8`? What nameserver(s) is/are VM2 using?

Comment: @hamiheim I am not able to ping 8.8.8.8 (network unreachable).To solve this, I added the same nameserver for VM2 than for VM1 (127.0.1.1), and now I get "Destination host unreachable". Is the problem in my routing tables?

Comment: Possibly. Run `traceroute 8.8.8.8` from VM2 and see where the packets are dropping.

Comment: They are indeed dropping after reaching 192.68.46.101 (VM1's interface to the Internal network). To resolve this, I tried to run the following commands:

Comment: Sounds like you don't have routing setup correctly on VM1. Can you post the `iptables` `nat` and `security` configs for VM1. 
`sudo iptables -t nat -L` and `sudo iptables -t security -L` respectively.

Comment: My iptables were empty. Now I understand the problem, thanks! I will post the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was actually missing some entries to iptables, added as follows:

```
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE
# iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o enp0s3 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o enp0s3 -j ACCEPT
```

with enp0s8 the interface to the outer world, and enp0s3 the interface to the Internal network.

Requests to the Internet from VM2 are now working... :)

Comment: I have one question,
what is for this rule: > iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o enp0s3 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
> if on next rule:
> iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o enp0s3 -j ACCEPT You are forwarding everything :)

Comment: @DominikKonczewski You're probably right, I wrote that a few years ago and probably didn't realise at the time that one rule overlapped the other.

Comment: your second rule should be `-i enp0s3 -o enp0s8` to accept return packets for established flows. You should also switch to the conntrack extension instead:
`iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s3 -o enp0s8 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`